# Fastest way to find powers of two higher than a number

Tags: python, math

I am trying to find a very fast way to find the next higher powers of 2 than a very large number (1,000,000) digits. Example, i have 1009, and want to find it's next higher powers of two which is 1024 or 2**10

I tried using a loop, but for large numbers this is very, very slow

```
y=0
while (1<<y)<1009:
   y+=1
print(1<<y)
1024
```

While this works, it's slow for numbers larger than a million digits. Is there a faster algorithm to find the next higher powers of 2 than a number that is large?

ANSWERED BY @JonClements

using 2**number.bit_length() works perfectly. So this will work for large numbers as well. Thanks Jon.

Here's a code example from Jon's implementation:

```
2**j.bit_length() 
1024
```

Here's a code example using the shift operator

```
2<<(j.bit_length()-1) 
1024
```

Here is the time difference using the million length number, the shift operator and bit_length is significantly faster:

```
len(str(aa))
1000000

def useBITLENGTHwithshiftoperator(hm):
  return 1<<hm.bit_length()-1<<1

def useBITLENGTHwithpowersoperator(hm):
  return 2**hm.bit_length()

start = time.time() 
l=useBITLENGTHwithpowersoperator(aa) 
end = time.time() 
print(end - start)                                                                                                                                 
0.014303922653198242                                                                                                                                             

start = time.time() 
l=useBITLENGTHwithshiftoperator(aa) 
end = time.time() 
print(end - start)                                                                                                                                 
0.0002968311309814453
```

Comment: If you have `n = 1024` is the next one 1024 or 2048?

Comment: I'm wondering if you could just use `2 ** n.bit_length()` where `n = 1009`... (although I suspect that'll need a little bit more work...)

Comment: @JonClements ooohhh, that might just work, i didn't know about bit_length

Comment: @oppressionslayer did you measure how much `bit_length()` takes for big numbers? so you can see if it is `O(n)` or `O(1)` ... if it is `O(n)` bit shifting using instead might be faster as you will obtain the wanted `2**?` as a byproduct

Answer (score 1):

take 2^ceiling(logBase2(x)) - should work unless x is a power of 2. and you can check for that with: `if x==ceiling(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not code in python but **millions of digits implies bignums** so:

1. **try to look inside your bignum lib**

   It might return the number of words or bits used in `O(1)` as some number representations need it to speed up other stuff. In such case you can obtain your answer in `O(1)` for free.

   As @JonClements suggested in a comments try `bit_length()` and measure if it is `O(1)` or `O(log(n))` ...
2. **Your `while` is `O(n^3)` instead of `O(n^2)`**

   You are bitshifting from 1 over and over again in each iteration. Why not just shift last result by 1 bit again instead? Something like

   ```
    for (y=0,yy=1;yy<1009;y++,yy<<=1);
   ```
3. **using `log2` might be faster**

   in case the bignum class you use have it implemented correctly after some number size threshold the `log2(1009)` might be signifficantly faster. But that depends on the type of numbers you using and bignum implementation itself.
4. **bit-shifting can be even faster**

   If you got some upper limit on your numbers you can use **binary search** converting your bitshifting into `O(n.log2(n))`.

   If not you can start bitshifting by 32 bits instead of by 1 when reached target size bitshift by 1 bit. Or even use more layers like `1024/128/16/1` bits. The complexity would be still `O(n^2)` but the constant time would be ~1024 times smaller speeding up ~1024 times your code for big numbers...

   Other option is to find the limit by shifting by 1 bit, then by 2 then by 4,8,16,32,64,... until result is bigger than your target number and from there either bitshift back or use binary search. This one would be `O(n.log2(n))` even without any upper limit..

   However all of these brings up much higher overhead and will slow down the processing of smaller numbers.

Constructing  `2^(y-1) < x <= 2^y` might be possible to enhance too. For example by using bit shifting approach to find the `y` you got your answer as byproduct for free. For example with floating point or fixed point numbers you can directly construct such number as computing exponent for 1 or by setting correct bit in the zero ... But for arbitrary numbers (where size of number is dynamic) i sthis much harder/slower. So all boils down what kind of bignums class you got and what values you use.

Comment: There's no bignum class per se, python's ints are already arbitrary precision.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I do not code in python so I did not know... so its integers and what base? Power of 2 dataword or power of 10 that fits into data word and what bitwidth? in other words what is the internal representation of the number as that can provide hints which approach to use efficiently, can be the datatwords accessed directly? or it uses strings? or BCD instead?

Comment: Yes, of course internally it's just a bignum implementation. It uses a base which is a power of 2, so bit_length() is a very fast function. Individual words are not directly accessible in python code.

Comment: @JamesKPolk well if the words are not accessible then I see no shortcut possible to generate the `2^bits` fast by constructing the number ... (you know pre-allocate space and set the single appropriate bit) except that the numbers would have implemented fast `exp2`  internally this way on its own ...

Comment: Right. It's likely that x << n is implemented as a special case if x is small enough to fit into a word, e.g. 1 << k should be nearly constant time.